# How can I find other solutions of the maze in java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, stack

I need to write a program that takes the maze in the given txt file and prints the solution paths to the console. I wrote this program as you can see below, but I can only find 1 solution. If there are more than 1 solution in the maze, I need to find all these. I have no idea what approach I should take for this. Can you give an idea, please?

Here is my work:

maze.txt (sent as argument)

```
11111111111111111
10110011000111111
11001110111001111
10110001011100111
11101111011011001
11101001011011111
11011011011001011
10111100111110111
11011011011111101
11100111011000011
10011110100111101
10100110111111101
11111111111111111
```

Driver Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Reading source file
        int rowNum = 0, colNum = 0;
        File mazeFile = new File(args[0]);

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mazeFile))) {
            System.out.println("Input of Readed File:\n");
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                colNum = line.length();
                rowNum++;
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //creating new maze array
        char[][] maze = new char[rowNum][colNum];
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("ROW: "+rowNum+" COL: "+colNum);

        //Setting maze's elements
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mazeFile))) {
            int readed,rNum=0,cNum=0;
            while ((readed = br.read()) != -1) {
                if(readed == 10){

                }
                else if(rNum<rowNum && cNum < colNum){
                    maze[rNum][cNum] = (char)readed;
                    cNum++;
                }
                else if(cNum >= colNum){
                    rNum++;
                    cNum=0;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Printing created maze...
        System.out.println("\nCreated Maze: \n");

        for (int i = 0; i<rowNum ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("\nSolution: \n");
        //Creating myStack object for making stack operations
        Stack myStack = new Stack(1000);

        //Creating mazeSolver object for solving maze
        MazeSolver mazeSolver = new MazeSolver(myStack,maze,1,1,colNum-2,rowNum-2,rowNum,colNum);
        mazeSolver.solve();

        //Printing inside of our stack.
        //myStack.showElements();

        //Creating answer array
        char[][] answer = maze;

        //Our path is drawn by re-reading the stored data in our stack structure.
        for (int i = rowNum-1; i >=0; i--) {
            for (int j = colNum-1; j >=0; j--) {
                int x[] = myStack.peek();
                if(i == x[0] && j == x[1]){
                    answer[i][j] = '#';
                }
            }
        }

        //Minor visual improvements ...
        for (int i = 0; i<rowNum ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                if(answer[i][j] == '1' || answer[i][j] == '0')
                    answer[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }

        //Printing our answer
        for (int i = 0; i<rowNum ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack Class:

```
public class Stack {
    int topOfStack;
    int capacity;
    int[][] Stack;

    public Stack(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        Stack = new int[capacity][2];
        topOfStack = -1;
    }

    void push(int y, int x)
    {
        if(topOfStack == capacity){
            System.out.println("Stack Overflow...");
        }
        else{
            Stack[++topOfStack] = new int[] { y, x };
        }
        //System.out.println("###Pushed Element: "+Stack[topOfStack][0]+" "+Stack[topOfStack][1]);
    }

    int[] pop() {
        if (topOfStack < 0) {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty...");
            return null;
        }
        //System.out.println("Pulled Element: "+Stack[topOfStack][0]+" "+Stack[topOfStack][1]);
        topOfStack--;
        return Stack[topOfStack];
    }

    int[] pop2() {
        if (topOfStack < 0) {
            System.out.println("Stack Underflow");
            return null;
        }
        else {
            int x[] = Stack[topOfStack--];
            //System.out.println("Pulled Element: "+x[0]+" "+x[1]);
            return x;
        }
    }

    int[] peek()
    {
        if (topOfStack < 0) {
            System.out.println("Stack Underflow");
            return null;
        }
        else {
            int x[] = Stack[topOfStack];
            return x;
        }
    }

    void showElements()
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        for (int i = topOfStack; i >=0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Stack Elements "+i+":"+" "+Stack[i][0] +" "+Stack[i][1]);
        }
    }

    int size(){
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= topOfStack; i++) {
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

MazeSolver Class:

```
public class MazeSolver {
    Stack workStack;
    char[][] maze;
    int startPointX;
    int startPointY;
    int endPointX;
    int endPointY;
    int numberOfRows;
    int numberOfCols;
    static final char Wall = '1';
    static final char Free = '0';
    static final char Success = '#';

    public MazeSolver(Stack workStack, char[][] maze,int startingPointX, int startingPointY, int endPointX, int endPointY, int RowNum, int ColNum) {
        this.workStack = workStack;
        this.maze = maze;
        this.startPointX = startingPointX;
        this.startPointY = startingPointY;
        this.endPointX = endPointX;
        this.endPointY = endPointY;
        this.numberOfRows = RowNum;
        this.numberOfCols = ColNum;
        workStack.push(startPointY,startingPointX);
    }

    boolean canMoveEast(){
        if((maze[startPointY][startPointX + 1] == Free) && (startPointX + 1 <= numberOfCols))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    boolean canMoveWest(){
        if((maze[startPointY][startPointX - 1] == Free) && (startPointX - 1 <= numberOfCols)){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    boolean canMoveNorth(){
        if((maze[startPointY-1][startPointX] == Free) && (startPointY - 1 <= numberOfRows)){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    boolean canMoveSouth(){
        if((maze[startPointY+1][startPointX] == Free) && (startPointY + 1 <= numberOfRows)){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    boolean canMoveNorthEast(){
        if((maze[startPointY-1][startPointX+1] == Free) && (startPointY - 1 <= numberOfRows) && (startPointX + 1 <= numberOfCols)){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    boolean canMoveNorthWest(){
        if((maze[startPointY-1][startPointX-1] == Free) && (startPointY - 1 <= numberOfRows) && (startPointX - 1 <= numberOfCols)){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    boolean canMoveSouthEast(){
        if((maze[startPointY+1][startPointX+1] == Free) && (startPointY + 1 <= numberOfRows) && (startPointX + 1 <= numberOfCols)){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    boolean canMoveSouthWest(){
        if((maze[startPointY+1][startPointX-1] == Free) && (startPointY + 1 <= numberOfRows) && (startPointX - 1 <= numberOfCols)){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    boolean solve()
    {
        maze[startPointY][startPointX] = Success;

        //Checked if we reached our goal
        if((startPointY == endPointY) && (startPointX == endPointX)){
            return true;
        }

        if(canMoveEast()){
            workStack.push(startPointY,startPointX+1);
            startPointX++;
            solve();
        }
        else if(canMoveWest()){
            workStack.push(startPointY,startPointX-1);
            startPointX--;
            solve();
        }
        else if(canMoveNorth()){
            workStack.push(startPointY-1,startPointX);
            startPointY--;
            solve();
        }
        else if(canMoveSouth()){
            workStack.push(startPointY+1,startPointX);
            startPointY++;
            solve();
        }
        else if(canMoveNorthEast()){
            workStack.push(startPointY-1,startPointX+1);
            startPointY--;
            startPointX++;
            solve();
        }
        else if(canMoveNorthWest()){
            workStack.push(startPointY-1,startPointX-1);
            startPointY--;
            startPointX--;
            solve();
        }
        else if(canMoveSouthEast()){
            workStack.push(startPointY+1,startPointX+1);
            startPointY++;
            startPointX++;
            solve();
        }
        else if(canMoveSouthWest()){
            workStack.push(startPointY+1,startPointX-1);
            startPointY++;
            startPointX--;
            solve();
        }
        else if(true){
            try {
                maze[startPointY][startPointX] = Wall;
                int[] back = workStack.pop();
                startPointY = back[0];
                startPointX = back[1];
                solve();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("There is no solution!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Output I Got:

```
Input of Readed File:

11111111111111111
10110011000111111
11001110111001111
10110001011100111
11101111011011001
11101001011011111
11011011011001011
10111100111110111
11011011011111101
11100111011000011
10011110100111101
10100110111111101
11111111111111111

ROW: 13 COL: 17
Created Maze: 

11111111111111111
10110011000111111
11001110111001111
10110001011100111
11101111011011001
11101001011011111
11011011011001011
10111100111110111
11011011011111101
11100111011000011
10011110100111101
10100110111111101
11111111111111111

Solution: 

.................
.#...............
..##...#.........
....###.#........
........#........
........#........
........#........
.......#.........
........#........
........#..####..
.........##....#.
...............#.
.................

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Output I Need:

```
Input of Readed File:

11111111111111111
10110011000111111
11001110111001111
10110001011100111
11101111011011001
11101001011011111
11011011011001011
10111100111110111
11011011011111101
11100111011000011
10011110100111101
10100110111111101
11111111111111111

ROW: 13 COL: 17
Created Maze: 

11111111111111111
10110011000111111
11001110111001111
10110001011100111
11101111011011001
11101001011011111
11011011011001011
10111100111110111
11011011011111101
11100111011000011
10011110100111101
10100110111111101
11111111111111111

Solution 1: 

.................
.#...............
..##...#.........
....###.#........
........#........
........#........
........#........
.......#.........
........#........
........#..####..
.........##....#.
...............#.
.................

Solution 2:

.................
.#...............
..##.............
....#............
...#.............
...#.............
..#..............
.#....##.........
..#..#..#........
...##...#..####..
.........##....#.
...............#.
.................

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @DevilsHnd What exactly is the defective part, sir? The program I have written is a program that can solve locally, including intermediate directions (Northeast, Northwest, Southeast, Southwest).

Comment: @DevilsHnd I kept the movement stages in the stack construction one by one with the backtracking process and I rewrote my maze by taking the contents of the stack construction. But this time, when the row and column numbers matched, it printed # instead of 1 or 0. For the remaining places "." dictated.

Answer (score 0):

The result you want is 'A variety of solutions which can go through (Northeast, Northwest) to (Southeast, Southwest)', and you need to solve using stack?
If so, I suggest you to use two stack, one for saving all possibilities(which store all toEast, toWest etc where you can go), one for saving current ongoings(each possible solutions, as a buffer)

Just add logic that saves current process in buffer, and print path when it Is a solution on your original code. If it's not a solution and cannot reach (Southeast, Southwest), traceback and restore your buffer stack. For this logic, you'll need another stack saving location where you last picked on from varieties of directions.

In short,

```
Stack1 => to save all possibilities
Stack2 => current paths. If not a solution, delete and restore
Stack3 => where you chose one direction from many. Need to traceback the path.

Stack2 copies Stack1 whenever you progress,
when reach the goal you print your Stack2 as a solution,
if not, pop until your latest decision informed by popping Stack3.
```