# How to find ALL possible solutions of a maze in Java

Tags: java, arrays, stack, backtracking, maze

I need to find all possible solutions of a maze. I have got maze.txt as follows:

```
11111111111111111
10110011000111111
11001110111001111
10110001011100111
11101111011011001
11101001011011111
11011011011001011
10111100111110111
11011011011111101
11100111011000011
10011110100111101
10100110111111101
11111111111111111
```

I wrote a program that solves mazes and I got this output in the end.

```
Solution 1: 

.................
.#...............
..##...#.........
....###.#........
........#........
........#........
........#........
.......#.........
........#........
........#..####..
.........##....#.
...............#.
.................
```

But there is one more solution like this:

```
Solution 2:

.................
.#...............
..##.............
....#............
...#.............
...#.............
..#..............
.#....##.........
..#..#..#........
...##...#..####..
.........##....#.
...............#.
.................
```

After I find the first solution, what kind of approach should I use for finding other ones too? If you need I can share my source code with you. Thanks a lot.

If you want source code, please check this : [How can I find other solutions of the maze in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847809/how-can-i-find-other-solutions-of-the-maze-in-java)

You can find all of my code over there and I'm asking same question simplier because noone aswered me in linked question and I think that thats because its too long. Just I need an idea for finding all possible ways.

Comment: Yes, please share your code.

Comment: Please help me understand how this is different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847809/how-can-i-find-other-solutions-of-the-maze-in-java), except the fact this one has no code in it.

Comment: @Milgo Done :))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find other solutions of the maze in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847809/how-can-i-find-other-solutions-of-the-maze-in-java)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I asked it but noone answered me just they liked it. And I decided to ask it simplier without codes and just I want an idea. But "Milgo" wanted my source code so I shared it for him too.

Comment: @Milgo İts my question bro and there is no answer :D

Comment: If you consider the start point "S" & end point "E" as "connected", then it's a closed circuit, and it's similar to a list of solutions to e.g. "route inspection problem" (aka Chinese postman problem, similar to traveling salesman problem), where you are trying to find the shortest path from S to E, but actually in that process just find all solutions (brute force) in order to select the shortest one. (There are various solutions & caveats.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem

Comment: @Roxox well, I'm sorry but that's not how stackoverflow works :) . If you don't receive answers, creating a new, identical question [is not the way to go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266338/how-can-i-improve-my-questions-or-how-to-get-more-attention-for-my-questions).

Comment: @michael Thank you for the suggestion, but if you look at the code I wrote, you will see that when I enter the dead-end streets, I mark my location as a "wall" and do the backtracking process. I think this may cause some roads to die. Could you please explain a little more clearly or by writing a protatip code?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thank you anyway for your concern, my friend :)

Comment: @NikolaiDmitriev Thanks bro, but I already did it in my solution. You can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847809/how-can-i-find-other-solutions-of-the-maze-in-java The problem is that how can I keep backtracking even if it has already finded solution.

Comment: *Approach for finding multiple solutions:* When you find a solution, **don't stop searching**, instead record the solution (e.g. add to a `List`), then continue the search algorithm. It's really quite that ***simple***.